# Life cycle callback prePersist not firing (using YAML files)

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I'm learning Symfony following The Book. In the tutorial, I successfully configured prePersist events (to set the createdAt field at insert time).

Now I'm trying to do the same but with YAML files instead of annotations. Here my orm.yml file:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Chronicle:
    type: entity
    table: chronicles
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: {strategy: AUTO}
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 256
        createdAt:
            type: datetime

    manyToOne:
        creator: 
            targetEntity: User
            inversedBy: chronicles
            joinColumn: 
                name: user_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        game:
            targetEntity: Game
            joinColumn:
                name: game_id
                referencedColumnName: id

    oneToMany:
        characters:
            targetEntity: Character
            mappedBy: chronicle

    lifeCycleCallbacks:
        prePersist: [ setCreatedAtValue ]
```

And this is a snippet of my entity class:

```
class Chronicle
{
    private $id;

    private $name;
    private $createdAt;

    // Associations
    private $game;
    private $creator;
    private $characters;
    // TODO: users or user relationships

    // Constructor
    public function __construct(User $creator=null) {
        $this->characters = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->creator = $creator;
    }

    /**
    * Set createdAt at the current time.
    *
    * (Lifecycle callback)
    */
    public function setCreatedAtValue() 
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }
    // ...
}
```

But the setCreatedAtValue() method is never called. So, I get an exception when I try to insert an object.

I have noticed that when using annotations I have to tell about the existence of lifecycle callbacks with the @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks() annotation, but I have not found anywhere an equivalent to that in yml, or if that is needed.

In a tutorial I have found I should register the callback in services.yml, but the tutorial never mention it, and I haven't found it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It will be called if you change "lifeCycleCallbacks" to "lifecycleCallbacks".